# Rails: Omniauth-twitter - retrieve image and description of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth, devise, omniauth

I have a rails app where users can sign in/up with omniauth through twitter.
It returns correct value for uid and nickname, but I can't retrieve profile image and description of users.

Here is more about my code:

**app/models/user.rb**

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.nickname
    user.image = auth.info.image
    user.description = auth.info.description
  end
end

def self.new_with_session(params, session)
  if session["devise.user_attributes"]
    new(session["devise.user_attributes"]) do |user|
      user.attributes = params
      user.valid?
    end
  else
    super
  end
```

In my view:

**app/views/users/show.html.erb**

```
<%= @user.name %> 
<%= @user.description %>
<%= image_tag @user.image %>
```

But it doesn't render the value from user's twitter account.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried printing auth.info to the console (or examining it using a debugger) to see what's being returned?

Answer (score 0):

It is working correcting now, the problem was that I was trying with the same account, who had already been logged in through twitter - so the new omniauth paramaters like description and image where not updated. I tried again with a new twitter account and it works perfectly.